# Java: Components disappearing after event

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm trying to make something for fun and my components keep disappearing after I press the "ok" button in my gui.

I'm trying to make a **"Guess a word"** program, where one will get a tip and you can then enter a guess and if it matches it will give you a message and if not, another tip. The problem is, if you enter something that's not the word it will give you a message that it's not the correct word and it will then give you another tip. But the other tip won't show up. They disappear.

I've two classes, **"StartUp"** and **"QuizLogic"**.
The problem arrives somewhere in the "showTips" method (I think).

If someone would try it themselves a link to the file can be found here: [Link to file](http://d.pr/f/KrDW)

Thank you.

```
public class StartUp {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JButton showRulesYesButton;
    private JButton showRulesNoButton;
    private JButton checkButton;

    private JPanel mainBackgroundManager;

    private JTextField guessEntery;

    private QuizLogic quizLogic;

    private ArrayList<String> tips;

    private JLabel firstTipLabel;
    private JLabel secondTipLabel;
    private JLabel thirdTipLabel;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public StartUp() {
        // Show "Start Up" message 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guess a Word!");
        showRules();
    }

    // METHODS
    public void showRules() {
        // Basic frame methods
        frame = new JFrame("Rules");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Creates JLabels and adds to JPanel
        JLabel firstRule = new JLabel("1. You will get one tip at a time of what the word could be.");
        JLabel secoundRule = new JLabel("2. You will get three tips and unlimited guesses.");
        JLabel thirdRule = new JLabel("3. Every word is a noun and in its basic form.");
        JLabel understand = new JLabel("Are you ready?");

        // Creates JPanel and adds JLabels to JPanel
        JPanel temporaryRulesPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 100, 60));

        temporaryRulesPanel.add(firstRule);
        temporaryRulesPanel.add(secoundRule);
        temporaryRulesPanel.add(thirdRule);
        temporaryRulesPanel.add(understand);

        // Initialize buttons
        showRulesYesButton = new JButton("Yes");
        showRulesNoButton = new JButton("No");

        showRulesYesButton.addActionListener(new StartUpEventHandler());
        showRulesNoButton.addActionListener(new StartUpEventHandler());

        // Creates JPanel and adds button to JPanel
        JPanel temporaryButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 100, 35));

        temporaryButtonPanel.add(showRulesYesButton);
        temporaryButtonPanel.add(showRulesNoButton);

        // Initialize and adds JPanel to JPanel
        mainBackgroundManager = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        mainBackgroundManager.add(temporaryRulesPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainBackgroundManager.add(temporaryButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Adds JPanel to JFrame
        frame.add(mainBackgroundManager);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void clearBackground() {
        mainBackgroundManager.removeAll();

        quizLogic = new QuizLogic();
        showGuessFrame();
        showTips();
    }

    public void showGuessFrame() {
        JPanel guessPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, 10));

        firstTipLabel = new JLabel("a");
        secondTipLabel = new JLabel("b");
        thirdTipLabel = new JLabel("c");

        tips = new ArrayList<String>();

        guessEntery = new JTextField("Enter guess here", 20);

        checkButton = new JButton("Ok");
        checkButton.addActionListener(new StartUpEventHandler());

        guessPanel.add(guessEntery);
        guessPanel.add(checkButton);

        mainBackgroundManager.add(guessPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(mainBackgroundManager);
    }

    public void showTips() {
        JPanel temporaryTipsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        temporaryTipsPanel.removeAll();

        tips.add(quizLogic.getTip());

        System.out.println(tips.size());

        if (tips.size() == 1) {
            firstTipLabel.setText(tips.get(0));
        }
        if (tips.size() == 2) {
            secondTipLabel.setText(tips.get(1));
        }
        if (tips.size() == 3) {
            thirdTipLabel.setText(tips.get(2));
        }

        temporaryTipsPanel.add(firstTipLabel);
        temporaryTipsPanel.add(secondTipLabel);
        temporaryTipsPanel.add(thirdTipLabel);

        mainBackgroundManager.add(temporaryTipsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(mainBackgroundManager);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public void getGuess() {
        String temp = guessEntery.getText();

        boolean correctAnswer = quizLogic.checkGuess(guessEntery.getText());

        if (correctAnswer == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good Job! The word was " + temp);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp + " is not the word we are looking for");
            showTips();
        }
    }

    private class StartUpEventHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == showRulesYesButton) {
                clearBackground();
            }
            else if (event.getSource() == showRulesNoButton) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Read the rules again");
            }
            else if (event.getSource() == checkButton) {
                getGuess();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class QuizLogic {

    private ArrayList<String> quizWord;
    private ArrayList<String> tipsList;

    private int tipsNumber;

    private String word;

    public QuizLogic() {
        tipsNumber = 0;

        quizWord = new ArrayList<String>();
        quizWord.add("Burger");

        try {
            loadTips(getWord());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public String getWord() {
        Random randomGen = new Random();        
        return quizWord.get(randomGen.nextInt(quizWord.size()));
    }

    public void loadTips(String word) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Oliver Nielsen\\Dropbox\\EclipseWorkspaces\\BuildingJava\\GuessAWord\\src\\domain\\" + word + ".txt"));

        this.word = word;
        tipsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
            tipsList.add(lineScanner.nextLine());
        }
    }

    public String getTip() {
        if (tipsNumber >= tipsList.size()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        String temp = tipsList.get(tipsNumber);
        tipsNumber++;

        System.out.println(temp);
        return temp;
    }

    public boolean checkGuess(String guess) {
        return guess.equalsIgnoreCase(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: this line "temporaryTipsPanel.removeAll();" might have been an issue in some form…I can't make full sense of all the code cuz it's just a lot, but this is what seems to make the most sense since you are narrowing it to the showTips method

Comment: And yet again i keep on repeating my self... Please paste only relevant code not the whole program. No one is gonna scan through all the lines for possible error.

Comment: User2277872: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to take a look at that.

Comment: Maciej Cygan: Sorry about that. I'm new here. But I'll keep that in mind. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

I don't know why it can't be done but if I deleted this line: `JPanel temporaryTipsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));`

and placed it in another method it worked. If someone could explain why that would be great but at least I/we know what was the problem.

Thank you. :)